# Server-Client Model Issue

Tags: c, sockets, networking, network-programming, winsock2

I have a TCP/IP Client and Server communicating with each other.

My Client is `recv`ing data from the server at an interval of 1 second viz. `sleep(1000)`. 
My server does not have a `sleep` provision.

It works fine if i am `recv`ing a simple string like "hi" .

But if i dont introduce sleep in my server , my client seems to be in a hanged state or processes a hugh bulk of data at once at the launch.

Is my server too supposed to `sleep` too ?

Or can be an issue with processing of `recv`ed data?

Comment: I don't understand. Why is your client sleeping?  What is the architecture of your server and what is it running on?

Comment: If you're using `sleep()` in the client to reduce CPU usage, you may want to look into using `select()`, `epoll()`, or some event library like libev.

Comment: @MartinJames well my client is sleeping because i am creating a thread  and then in that i am polling (calling `select`) on multiple sockets if any and then receiving any data sent to me by the server. All this happens in a While Loop. so as rightly said by Ioan, to save on the CPU usage i am precisely doing that

Answer (score 1):

If your server is writing to the socket without a sleep then it will fill the TCP buffer on both sides very quickly, your client will then almost immediately have a load of data stuck in its local buffer to read.  If you are looking to have the server be delayed by the sleep on your client then you can do it as a transaction instead where the server writes the string but then reads a byte.  The client would then read the string and write one byte to signify that it had received it.  This would keep the server in step with the client.